# Class not found while library is there

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, opencsv

I'm trying to use the OpenCsv library.When trying to instantiate a StatefulBeanToCsv for writing to a csv with

```
StatefulBeanToCsv<Addresses> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<Addresses>(output)
                            .build();
```

I get the following exception

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap

while the dependency to commons-collections4 is there

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

which includes the ListValueMap.

I have re-built,cleaned,compiled the project,checked the classpath but the error persists! this is what the dependency tree shows

```
+- com.opencsv:opencsv:jar:5.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem based on the information in the question. What version of OpenCSV are you using and what does that Maven dependency look like? What else do you have in your pom.xml? Your question tags mention other libraries such as POI and Spring - so maybe there is a library conflict. Can you narrow down the problem by starting with just a plain OpenCSV project and then adding other dependencies?

Comment: (Just to note: The current version of OpenCSV ([5.7.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv/5.7.0)) has Commons Collections 4 as a transitive Maven dependency, so you should not even need to add that explicitly to your POM.)

Comment: @andrewJames this is what the dependency tree shows : +- com.opencsv:opencsv:jar:5.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile

Comment: How are you making sure that all the dependency jars are present at *runtime* and not just at compile time?